Does the causal closure principle necessitate the non causal role of consciousness?
The causal closure of the physical states that every physical event has a physical explanation. In other words, whenever there is a sufficient cause of a physical event, there is a sufficient physical cause of that event.
The movement of my hand is a physical event. If the causal closure principle is true, does this not trivially imply that my mental decision cannot possibly play a causal role in moving my hand, given that mental events are not physical events?
I suppose that identity theorists may get around this issue by positing that mental states just are brain states, but then the cause of my arm's movement would then remain to be physical, since brain states are also physical.

"given that mental events are not physical events" - under reductive physicalism, mental events are physical events.

@user80226 as far as I know, physicalism allows for different theories about how the mental relates to the physical. Identity theory, on the other hand, insists on a direct identity between mental and physical states. Identity theory is a type of physicalism

Sorry, I meant reductive physicalism.

As argued by David Chalmers neutral monism, so long as you accept the very existence of non-physical consciousness, physical causal closure cannot explain the cause of consciousness due to the possibility of p-zobmbies which are conceivable. Of course if you regard consciousness as non-physical and reject Aristotle's famous 4-cause theory, then consciousness necessarily doesn't play any causal role such as its traditional efficient causal role...

@DoubleKnot causal closure states that every physical effect has a physical cause, not that physical causes do not have non physical effects, or that physical causes do not generate non physical things, or that non physical things do not supervene on the physical.

What is "physical" is getting harder to define all the time --  there are some theories of fundamental physics that posit everything is "spin networks" (damned if I know what that is). I am partial to awareness being synonomoys with "information" as the core substrate of reality -- matter, energy etc are emergent from information dynamics.

@Annika true. it's unfortunate that so many philosophical discussions end up being semantic.

If you understand modern physical causal closure that way, then this is just Aristotle's material cause within his famous 4-cause theory, then your confusion can be easily desolved since there're still other causes...

If (1) physical events must have physical causes; and (2) mental events are not physical events; then mental events cannot cause a physical event.
Propositions (1) and (2) appear to be premises of the question.
If you go further and stipulate that consciousness is a mental event, then you can also conclude that consciousness cannot cause a physical event.

The proof is in the pudding.

IMO the approach is too simple to solve the issue of causal closedness within the narrow bounds of the argumentation from the original question.

Human individuals experience certain mental states as conscious
states. Often those are states where the individuum decides between
several possible actions.

Each mental state has a meaning for the individuum. The meaning
is the set of all similar mental states, which are linked to the
given state because they are similar.
The link is in the memory of
the individuum.
A linked state can be the trigger to activate
certain motor neurons, which previously produced an advanteous
feedback for the individuum.

That’s only a broad sketch how neuroscience attempts to bridge
conscious mental states and physical action. The key concept is the
“meaning” of a mental state, the meaning for the individual organism.
For a more
elaborated presentation see Kevin Mitchell: Free Agents: How
Evolution Gave Us Free Will, Chapter 9 "Meaning".


IMO the
neuroscientific research presented in Mitchell book shows a mechanism which supports the
hypothesis: The causal closure principle supports the causal role of
conscious mental processes.
But that's ongoing research, probably not the final answer of the issue.

No; the causal closure principle would only necessitate the non-causal role of consciousness under the assumption that consciousness is non-physical.
Why make that assumption?
What does "physical" mean? There are several possible definitions for this word, and there is no objective way to prefer one over the other; it ultimately comes down to a matter of convention. Reasonably we might say, something is physical if it is (in theory, at least) amenable to investigation by the physical sciences. Then, to say that consciousness is non-physical is to say that it can never be investigated by the physical sciences. Although some philosophers agree with that, it's quite a controversial claim - much more controversial than the causal closure principle!
Or we might define something as "physical" if it causally interacts with other things called physical. This has the nature of an inductive definition; we define some familiar objects, such as chairs, to be physical as the base case, and then other objects are defined to be physical in the inductive case if they causally interact with other objects already labeled "physical," and we iterate until there are no additional objects to label "physical." But under this definition, we don't have a reason to conclude consciousness is non-physical, unless we already assume it doesn't causally interact, which would be begging the question.
Or we might define something as "physical" if it lacks subjective experience. But this seems to be simply defining-away the problem. And how do you know that causal closure holds, if you define "physical" in this way? To assert causal closure under this definition you would have to assume a dualist, non-interacting model, which would again be begging the question.

You ask: If the causal closure principle is true, does this not trivially imply that my mental decision cannot possibly play a causal role in moving my hand, given that mental events are not physical events?
Do you think that that mental decision comes about without any neurons firing?
If so, don't you think that those firing neurons in turn could effect other motor neurons firing and hence move your hand?

They can, but those firing neurons would be physical events, and not mental events, unless you are an identity theorist

Exactly my point. But there's still a mental event or not? Yet, physical closure is accounted for.

There seems to of course be a mental event but the question is whether or not it plays a causal role if physical events can only have physical causes

How could it if you pose that physical effects can only have physical causes? But I showed you a mechanism by which your hand is moving.  Unless you want to believe that mental events are unrelated to neuronal interactions  ..

epiphenomenalism doesn’t state that mental events do not exist, nor does it state that mental events are unrelated to neuronal interactions, for they may supervene on those interactions. It states instead that those experiences play no causal role. This is similar to a steam whistle that contributes nothing to the work of a locomotive

I was not arguing any of that. I simply gave you an account per your question that shows how causal closure can be maintained.
